# Using IOptionsSnapshot<> is not working when deployed on Azure App Service?

Tags: c#, azure, configuration, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0

I just want to use `IOptionsSnapshot<>` to be able to do config changes on the fly on my website and it gets applied without restarting the app.

It should be pretty straightforward, here's what I have coded.

The `appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "ConfigWebsite": {
    "CanRegister": true
  }
}
```

The ConfigWebsiteOptions class to represent the custom section:

```
namespace Example
{
    public class ConfigWebsiteOptions
    {
        public bool CanRegister { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my `Program.cs` (see line 2):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<ConfigWebsiteOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConfigWebsite"));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

In one of my pages, for example `Error.cshtml.cs`:

```
namespace Example
{
    public class ErrorModel
    {
        public ConfigWebsiteOptions Options { get; set; }

        public ErrorModel(
            IOptionsSnapshot<ConfigWebsiteOptions> options
            )
        {
            this.Options = options.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

And I am using the different values in the `Options` property on my cshtml page (e.g. `@Model.Options.CanRegister`).

---

It's working, I can change the value in the `appsettings.json` file and the change gets applied

- in Debug on my machine
- in Release when published in a Folder Profile and ran on my machine

---

It's somehow **not** working

- in Release when published to an Azure App Service

The value used on my page always stays the same (first read) and never gets updated when I change the file, until a server restart.

How could it be explained that it's working on all but my Prod environment and how to fix that?

Comment: Not a direct solution to your problem, but the recommended approach for this is probably to use App Service configuration values (change causes restart) or Azure App Configuration (no restart required).

Comment: How are you modifying your appsettings.json after deploying to azure app service ?

Comment: @CodingMytra connecting by FTP, downloading the appsettings.json file there, modifying locally then reuploading it

Comment: @bruno any chance your ftp is not changing the timestamp on the file?  Also, do you have an appsettings.{environment}.json file?

Comment: @BoxOfNotGoodery yes updating the file via FTP is updating the file timestamp. Yes there is an `appsettings.Development.json` but I don't think it's used.